# Variables, different contexts in a single page

Tags: php

Hi I'm tring to use same variable in two different contexts in a single page.

```
some html
<?php
   $variable1="sample"
?>

some html

<?php
   $variable2=variable1
?>
some html
```

I know creating session is a solution. But I'm not sure if its suitable to create a session for this.

Comment: What you show should work, no need for sessions. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with normal variables. You just forgot the $-sign in the second part. And you really should add semicolons.